# Js function works in IE9 not working in IE11

Tags: java, javascript, struts

I am using a JS function in a jsp page and it works fine in IE9. It is not working in IE11.

in jsp:

```
<button onClick="moveSelectedOptions(this.form['availableUseCases'],this.form['groupUseCases'],true)"></button>
```

and the function in js goes like this :

```
function moveSelectedOptions(from,to) {

// Move them over
for (var i=0; i<from.options.length; i++) {
    var o = from.options[i];
    if (o.selected) {
        to.options[to.options.length] = new Option( o.text, o.value, false, false);
    }
}
// Delete them from original
for (var i=(from.options.length-1); i>=0; i--) {
    var o = from.options[i];
    if (o.selected) {
        from.options[i] = null;
    }
}
if ((arguments.length<3) || (arguments[2]==true)) {
    sortSelect(from);
    sortSelect(to);
}
from.selectedIndex = -1;
to.selectedIndex = -1;
}
```

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: Hi that is a function to move some component list to and from two dropdown list...... So in IE9 the addition and removal of components works fine,, In IE11 the addition and removal is not working

Comment: You can't remove from the list while iterating it, create a new list and copy what you want from it.

Comment: I don't see any list removal operations here. In any case, there likely isn't enough information to really help--start debugging.

Comment: This works, when i change <button> tag to <input type="button"....>